# It was your choice; idiom or expression

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there an expression or idiom used when someone has done something that hasn't had the desired result after being warned about it, to mean *"It was your choice and now it's the result"*? Like he can't blame anyone else for that.

Comment: [You pays your money, you takes your choice](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/you-pays-your-money-and-you-takes-your-choice-chance).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synonym request: "paint into a corner"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293691/synonym-request-paint-into-a-corner)

Comment: Not an idiom, but if said with the just the right all-knowing facial expression and nod, the single word "Self-imposed" conveys the idea nicely.

Comment: Are you speaking about the person or to the person? And is the emphasis on them making a poor choice or on them not listening to you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"***You've made your bed ...***" (now lie in it).

Or,

***"Your chickens have come home to roost."***

Or,

***"You've sown the wind ..."*** (now reap the whirlwind).

Comment: +1 for "You've made your bed", first thing that came to mind after reading the title.

Answer (score 5):

I think  ***"[it serves you right](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/learner-inglese/it-serves-her-him-you-right)"*** may suggest the idea you are referring to:

> - (informal)   something you say about a bad thing that has happened to a person and that they deserve.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 4):

Possibly, in addition to the other suggestions, also "[You reap what you sow.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/reap+what+sow)"

> to experience the results of your own actions
>
> *If we neglect our*
>   *environment, we will surely reap what we sow.*
>
> Usage notes: usually
>   used to say that something bad is likely to result from an activity
>
> Etymology: from the idea that the quality of the seeds that you sow
>   (put into the ground) grow into the kind of plants that you are able
>   to reap (cut and collect)

Comment: This really should be a comment.

Comment: Possibly, sorry about that.  Would it improve matters if I cited a source?

Comment: Yes, it would; see, e.g.,  JG's  answer.

Comment: It's a perfectly good answer, not a comment, but it does need a definition/citation.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether your emphasis is on the fact that they made a poor choice, or the fact that they ignored your wise advice.

Several of the good answers you've gotten emphasize the latter: the person made a poor choice and now has to live with the consequences of that choice.

But if you wanted to emphasize that they didn't listen to you, "I told you so", and variants might be appropriate. By variants, I mean things like the faux denial: "I hate to say 'I told you so', but...", or "I'm not one to say 'I told you so', but...".

Another option is, "Well, some people just have to learn the hard way", which makes note of the fact that they ignored advice, but doesn't emphasize the fact that it was *your* advice.

Comment: This is a good question to ask for clarification, but do that in a comment on the question, not in an answer.

Comment: Hi, Wayne, It would be better if you could delete the first paragraph and elaborate more on "I told you so!" part. Please let me know when it is done. I will upvote your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Rathony: Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar to Hot Licks' comment, you could say they **[paid the price](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Pay+The+Price)**:

> - Fig. to suffer the consequences for doing something or risking something. Oh, my head! I am paying the price for drinking too much last night.
> - to accept the unpleasant results of what you have done She dropped all her friends when she met Steve and now that he's gone, she's paying the price. She has no one to turn to. (often + for ) I have paid the price for working nonstop - my health has suffered.

Answer (score 1):

***get what's coming to one***

> Receive what one deserves or is due, especially something unpleasant, such as a punishment or rebuke. For example, *When they suspended Steve for cheating, he was only getting what was coming to him*. [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+what%27s+coming+to+one).

***have it coming***

> Deserve what one receives, as in *You may not like being reprimanded, but you have to admit you had it coming*, or *When he won the Nobel Prize, everyone said he'd had it coming for a long time*. [c. 1900] [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+it+coming)